# iphone application with HTML

Tags: iphone, html

I have an iPhone applcation in which I want to take facebook user's friends name. I got that friend list in an array. Now I want to display this array value in htmlpage. Later this html page display on iphone screen. So how can I call the friendslist from HTML page and display the name one by one. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pull that off in plain HTML. But using a scripting language like PHP looping over an array is very simple:

```
<?php
//friendsList is the array containing the names you want to loop over
foreach ($friendsList as $friend) {
  echo $friend;
}
?>
```

This snippet of code only works if your page has a .php extension. So serving it as .html won't work.